# Why is header image not responsive?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive

Trying to figure out why the header image for my site is non-responsive.

From what I've read, this should do it with a width of 100% on the containing element.

https://super-lollipop-a72757.netlify.app/

```
.intro {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(../img/big_logo.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Header component

```
import logo from '../images/logo2.png';

export const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <header id='header'>
      <div className='intro'>
        <div className='overlay'>
          <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 intro-text'>
                <h1>
                  {/* {props.data ? props.data.title : 'Loading'} */}
                  <img style={{marginBottom:"20px"}} src={logo} alt="logo" />
                  <span></span>
                </h1>
                <p>{props.data ? props.data.paragraph : 'Loading'}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

It works fine with images I've tested from the gallery too. But, for some reason when adding the logo as the header image, it doesn't work right.

Comment: `cover` means "resize this image so that it covers both width and height, and if one of those is too large, too bad". So what does "responsive" mean here? "full width, variable height"? If so you just want `background-size: 100%`.

Comment: ```background-attachment: fixed;``` is stopping your image to be set in responsive. If I were you I will use separate div for setting image in backgroubd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `background-size: contain` vs `cover`

As [Chris Coyier summarized here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/#:%7E:text=cover%20tells%20the%20browser%20to,to%20the%20sides%20or%20bottom.), `background-size` can provide various options, and `cover` might not be you're looking for here.

`cover` is focused on ensuring there's no space uncovered—practically extending the background image to all four edges beyond the containing boundaries. `contain`, on the other hand, is focused on ensuring there's no cropping happening on the background image—practically leaving uncovered areas blank.

If you intend your big image to remain intact, uncropped, and readable at all times, try adding the following to your `.intro` class.

```css
background-size: contain;
background-color: #426CB4;
```

You already have your `background-position: center` as part of your `background` shorthand, so this should cover it. `background-color` line helps to fill the container with the same color as the logo background.

Comment: That did it. That makes more sense. I always stunk at CSS lol Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your intro element in CSS file. This will fix your problem.

```
  display: flex;
  background: url(../img/big_logo.jpg) center center no-repeat center;
background-attachment: fixed;
 height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That, unfortunately, did not work.